# How to use a function to convert several columns with a character value into binary numeric in a huge data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a huge data.frame with numeric, characters and missing values. How do I convert all "True" and "False" (characters values) into 1 and 0, while preserving the missing values?

I tried using dplyr recode  function, but it does not apply to object of class data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = 150:154 , Var2 = c("True","True","","False","True"), 
Var3 = c("","True","True","False","True"), 
Var4 = 1116:1120, Var99 = c("","True","","False","True"))
```

```
> df
  Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4 Var99
1  150  True       1116      
2  151  True  True 1117  True
3  152        True 1118      
4  153 False False 1119 False
5  154  True  True 1120  True
```

## and my output would be:

```
> df2
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var99
1  150    1      1116      
2  151    1    1 1117     1
3  152         1 1118      
4  153    0    0 1119     0
5  154    1    1 1120     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `mutate_if` and recode the values to 1, 0 with `fct_recode` from `forcats`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>% 
   mutate_if(is.factor, list(~ fct_recode(.,  "1" = "True", "0" = "False" )))
#    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var99
#1  150    1      1116      
#2  151    1    1 1117     1
#3  152         1 1118      
#4  153    0    0 1119     0
#5  154    1    1 1120     1
```

NOTE: The columns were not logical (`TRUE/FALSE`) instead it was (`True/False`).  So, keeping the dataset object as such and without any other assumptions

NOTE2: Will not change the column types after the transformation

---

For changing to numeric, it can be done with `match`

```
df %>%
     mutate_if(is.factor,  list( ~ match(., c("False", "True")) - 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dplyr functions `mutate_if` and `case_when`. For simplicity, set stringsAsFactors to FALSE when creating the data.frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = 150:154 , Var2 = c("True","True","","False","True"), 
                 Var3 = c("","True","True","False","True"), 
                 Var4 = 1116:1120, Var99 = c("","True","","False","True"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.character, ~case_when(. == "True" ~ 1L, 
                                       . == "False" ~ 0L, 
                                       . == "" ~ NA_integer_))
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R approach with `as.logical` and `as.numeric`:

```
> df[c("Var2", "Var3", "Var99")] <- lapply(df[c("Var2", "Var3", "Var99")], function(x){
+   as.numeric(as.logical(x))
+ })
> df
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var99
1  150    1   NA 1116    NA
2  151    1    1 1117     1
3  152   NA    1 1118    NA
4  153    0    0 1119     0
5  154    1    1 1120     1
```

Also, like @IceCreamToucan said, if you don´t want to type varaible names, use:

```
> vars_logic <- sapply(df, function(x) {all(x %in% c('True', 'False', ''))})
> 
> df[vars_logic] <- lapply(df[vars_logic], function(x){
+   as.numeric(as.logical(x))
+ })
> 
> df
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var99
1  150    1   NA 1116    NA
2  151    1    1 1117     1
3  152   NA    1 1118    NA
4  153    0    0 1119     0
5  154    1    1 1120     1
```

Comment: And if you don't want to type out the variable names, you can use something like `sapply(df, is.factor)` or `sapply(df, function(x) all(x %in% c('True', 'False', '')))` in place of `c("Var2", "Var3", "Var99")`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I like that! If you dont mind I add it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that all of the columns with True/False are factors, you can try this `dplyr` solution (however, also look at the notes provided by @akrun):

```
df %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, list(~ as.logical(.) * 1))

  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var99
1  150    1   NA 1116    NA
2  151    1    1 1117     1
3  152   NA    1 1118    NA
4  153    0    0 1119     0
5  154    1    1 1120     1
```

Or a slight modification based on the idea from @Santiago Capobianco:

```
df %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, list(~ as.numeric(as.logical(.))))
```